# 01847. 00000 - "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure new_user as
begin
fnd_user_pkg.createuser('BOBBY','oracle123',TO_DATE('7-FEB-2017'),NULL,TO_DATE('20-02-17'),'80','78960','bobby@gmail.com');
end;
```

I am calling the above procedure using command as below:

```
exec new_user();
```

Procedure complies successfully, but on executing error encountered is:

> Error starting at line : 7 in command - BEGIN new_user(); END; Error
>   report - ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of
>   month ORA-06512: at "APPS.NEW_USER", line 3 ORA-06512: at line 1
>   01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
>   *Cause:    
>   *Action:

Can someone help me?

Comment: i´d never parse a date without any formatmask, as you are bound the the format provided by the database this way. If it differs from your format you´ll be getting an exception like this. And as you are already providing two different types of formats this is doomed to fail without the formatmask.

Comment: you should send the date format even with the `to_date` function like `TO_DATE('07-02-2017','DD-MM-YYYY')`

Comment: If possible, you should use date literals anyway instead of converting strings. A date literal looks like this: `DATE '2017-02-07'`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm curious as to why you say `you _should_ use date literals ... instead of converting strings`... the ANSI date literal is a string-to-date conversion! (Oracle converts it to a `to_date()` behind the scenes anyway, as evidenced by checking the explain plan for `SELECT * FROM dual WHERE SYSDATE >= DATE '2017-01-01';` - you get `filter(SYSDATE@!>=TO_DATE(' 2017-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))`)

Comment: @Boneist: The SQL standard defines a date literal as `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`. So this *is* a date. There is nothing to convert. Don't let the quotes confuse you; the standard could just as well have defined a date literal as, say, `§YYYYMMDD§`. And how Oracle currently parses literals internally shouldn't be our concern, really.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sure, it's a date. I wasn't questioning that. But so is `to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`. I was more interested in why you say we **should** use a date literal above and beyond the standard Oracle `to_date()` function. I mean, the ANSI date literal doesn't include time, so in fact it's quite restrictive. Also, saying we shouldn't be concerned about how Oracle handles things is, IMHO, bad practice; if you want to make best use of the database, you should be concerned about how it handles things.

Comment: @Boneist: `TO_DATE` is an Oracle function to convert a string into a date. Why would I put a conversion function  on a string literal in the query, when I can put in the date directly? Same for other literals. I would not write `where id = TO_NUMBER('123')` when I can simply write `where id = 123` instead. Why should I? I use string literals for strings, date literals for dates and numeric literals for numbers. (By the way the literal for a datetime/timestamp is `TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'` plus optional fractional seconds.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the TIMESTAMP literal is of TIMESTAMP not DATE datatype. If you were using the ANSI TIMESTAMP literal to store data into a DATE column or variable, you're causing an unnecessary datatype conversion. IMHO, there is no "you **should** use the ANSI DATE/TIMESTAMP literal above the to_date/to_timestamp functions"; the ANSI literals may save you more typing, but the to_* functions give you more flexibility. And they do the same thing under the covers. There is no one-true-way here. Again, IMHO. The only important thing is treating dates as dates, not as strings, numbers, etc *{;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is probably because of the `formatting of the to_date() function`

Here are a fer examples for reference :

```
 to_date('29-Oct-09', 'DD-Mon-YY')
 to_date('10/29/09', 'MM/DD/YY')
 to_date('120109', 'MMDDYY')
 to_date('29-Oct-09', 'DD-Mon-YY HH:MI:SS') 
 to_date('Oct/29/09', 'Mon/DD/YY HH:MI:SS')
 to_date('October.29.2009', 'Month.DD.YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

you could also refer [this link](https://ss64.com/ora/syntax-to_date.html) for further reference.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Khushi the second conversion that you are doing probably has a wrong sequence, try it like '20-2-17' , 'DD-Mon-YY'

Comment: tried it but still error is:   ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: just have a reference to [this link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01843.php). it is some minor issue with the format mask!

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: @Khushi My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple formats in your `to_date`s, but are not defining them.

```
create or replace procedure new_user as
begin
fnd_user_pkg.createuser('BOBBY',
                        'oracle123',
                        TO_DATE('7-FEB-2017', 'D-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'), -- definition here, 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN' can be omitted if your language is set to English
                        NULL,
                        TO_DATE('20-02-17','DD-MM-YY'), -- definition here
                        '80',
                        '78960',
                        'bobby@gmail.com');
end;
```

Comment: Note that the format mask `'D-MON-YYYY'` depends on the NLS language of the _client_ It will e.g. fail for a client computer that is configured for French

Comment: I agree with a_horse_with_no_name; when dealing with names, such as `'FEB'` always state the NLS date language in TO_DATE's third parameter: `TO_DATE('7-FEB-2017', 'D-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')`.

Comment: After trying this error is:Error(3,162): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:     := . ( % ;      Error(3,194): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     . ( ) , * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset